# print a list with multiple types (int and list) as a set

Tags: python, list, printing, set

I have to print A (either int or list) as a set.

For example:

How would I print `[[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]` as a set? when I do `set()` with that list inside the `()`, it returns with error: `unhashable type`.

I know I can use recursion, so far I have:

```
def printSet (A):
    if A == int:
      print (A)
    else:
```

.. but I don't know what else I should do. please help!

I don't need any fancy libraries or anything, just recursion. However, if there is an iterable way to do it, I'll also take that.

Comment: Im confused on what you mean by "as a set". Do you mean remove duplicates, or just print out each value in the inner lists.

Comment: You want the output to be a list of sets? Can you post exactly what you want the output to be?

Comment: @chrisz output should be {1,2}, {4,5,6], {9}, {} of the list mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, sets cannot be nested. However, you can create a set wrapper to create a representation of nested sets:

```
class SetWrapper:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.v = set() if not args else args
  def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, str(self))
  def __str__(self):
    return '{'+', '.join(str(i) for i in self.v)+'}'


def wrap_set(f):
   def wrapper():
     return SetWrapper(*[i if type(i) not in [list, set] else SetWrapper(*i) for i in f()])
   return wrapper

@wrap_set
def get_list():
   return [[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]  

print(get_list())
```

Output:

```
SetWrapper({{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {9}, {}})
```

Comment: this definitely works but is there a way to do it without a set wrapper? i'm not allowed to use one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly `A` is a list that contains either objects of type `list` or objects of type `int`

```
for elem in A:
    if isinstance(elem, int):
         print(elem)
    elif isinstance(elem, list):
         print(set(elem))
```

If you have lists of lists of lists you can easily turn this into a recursive function

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list comprehension or generator expression.

```
[set(x) for x in [[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]]
print(*(set(x) for x in [[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]])) # prints "{1, 2} {4, 5, 6} {9} set()"
```

If you really want to use recursion here is one way to do it:

```
def fn(x):
    if type(x)==int:
        return x
    else:
        try:
            return set(x)
        except TypeError:
            return [fn(y) for y in x]
```

Comment: no, i would need the output to be {1,2}, {4,5,6], {9}, {}

Answer (score 0):

One way using `list comprehension`

```
mylist = [[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]
[ {} if not l else set(l) for l in mylist ]
#[{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {9}, {}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try lambda :

```
data=[[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]

print(list(map(lambda x:set(x),data)))
```

output:

```
[{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {9}, set()]
```

if you don't want that set() then filter the result :

```
data=[[1,2],[4,5,6],[9],[]]
print(list(filter(lambda y:y!=set(),(map(lambda x:set(x),data)))))
```

output:

```
[{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {9}]
```